# Changing Flutter's version using git instead of [flutter upgrade], will this cause problems?

Tags: flutter

If there is a bug in flutter itself it may not be obvious which version of flutter it is fixed in so experimenting a bit with running the code in different versions is required.  It takes a long time to switch between different versions of flutter and therefore a really long time to do a little bit of trial and error in this way.

What exactly does `flutter upgrade` do?  Will it cause problems if I just went into the flutter install directory and did a `git checkout v1.23.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some items that are cached based on values in the git archive, such as which version of git goes with this version of flutter. (Those are baked in.) I believe `flutter precache` will upgrade those without changing the checked out commit.

Comment: thanks, I run ```flutter doctor``` too, when I do that I think it fetches the correct version of Dart for the version of Flutter that was installed

Comment: @atreeon meant version of dart